# Search if an element exists in a associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an loop as below:

```
for( $m = 0; $m < count( $spcl_holiday_list_r ); $m++ )
{

    $region_str = $spcl_holiday_list_r[$m]['region'];

    $region_arr =  explode(",",$region_str);

    var_dump( $region_arr ) ;

    if( in_array( $hq_id , $region_arr ) )
    {
        $special_holidays += $special_holidays;
    }
}
}
echo $special_holidays;
```

The `var_dump( $region_arr )` shows :

```
array
  0 => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => string '4' (length=1)
  2 => string '5' (length=1)
  3 => string '7' (length=1)
  4 => string '10' (length=2)
array
  0 => string '3' (length=1)
array
  0 => string '10' (length=2)
```

The `in_array( $hq_id , $region_arr )` always returns `FALSE` ! So I want to know how the function `in_array()` is implemented for associative array? Looking at my array output and requirement , `array_key_exists` is also not an option for me.

Comment: If it returns `false` then that is because `$hq_id` does not exist in the array. So what about `var_dump($hq_id)`? Also, you should prefer `foreach` over `for` unless there is a reason to use the latter (most of the time there is not).

Comment: `hq_id` is `10` for this case. So I want the total to be `2`.

Comment: `var_dump($hq_id)` -- please don't make me beg.

Comment: did you tried `array_walk_recursive` yet?

Comment: `string '10' (length=2)`

Comment: `$special_holidays += $special_holidays;` = `0 + 0 + 0 + ...`

Comment: @Yoshi: Congrats! :-)

Comment: @Yoshi :) . `$special_holidays++;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be using array_search() instead.
Watch out for the return value possibly being a boolean

```
if ( array_search($hq_id , $region_arr) !== FALSE )
```

[PHP Manual array)search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)